# Removing a Group from Offline Global Address List in Powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange, office365, azure

This is for an Azure Office365 tenant:

Basically, when I run a an object query against a group like this:

Get-UnifiedGroup "GroupName" | Select Object *

It gives me a list of all the different attributes and their settings.

Under the attribute "AddressListMembership" it shows:

AddressListMembership: {**\Offline Global Address List**, \All Groups, \All Distribution Lists, \GroupMailboxes(VLV)...}

**What is the command to remove \Offline Global Address List from AddressListMembership?**

I've tried: Get-UnifiedGroup family | Set-UnifiedGroup HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true

This does remove from the GAL but not the Offline one.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If you close outlook and delete the OAB files on the local machine in the offline address book, if you rename this folder to .old then restart outlook the offline address book will resync.